# Bind a Exe and a ZIP file in one Zip file for a minecraft resource pack

Tags: zip

I want to bind a Exe and a ZIP file in one Zip file for a minecraft resource pack so when I open the zip file it opens the .zip file and the .exe at the same time.
I have already tried a couple of methods and binders but they just open the zip file and not the exe. I need to open them both at the same time.
I hope anyone can help me ;) 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just not create a self-extracting zip file?  This won't achieve your goal of starting the executable from within the archive, but you could create a .bat, which might achieve your goals.  If the .exe is within the .zip file its not clear though what you want to stat at the same time, the executable can't be started, until its extracted.

Comment: The expected operation the archive is to open/view it's contents while never executing those contents. So to have this functionality built into archivers is unlikely to exist or it would create a huge vulnerability.

Comment: Just type "hack zipfile.zip virus.exe -c" in command prompt and let windows handle the rest, good luck fellow 1337 h4x0r

Answer (score 3):

Because people like surprises?

It's a zip.  Opening it should just open the archive, not start something executing.   That'd be awfully malwareish.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a proper ZIP file, even if there is a header that makes the file also be a proper EXE file, then I can use my own software to "open" the ZIP file.  There are multiple programs that can handle standard ZIP files.  ZIP files are just data, so the ZIP file cannot really perform any actions (data doesn't do that), so the ZIP file cannot prevent me from doing that.  (The only way the file could prevent that is if the file is not actually a (proper) ZIP file.)

What is possible is to make a "self extracting ZIP file".  That means that the file is an executable file.  Then, opening the file on a supported operating system will run the executable file, which can do things like extract files, or perhaps start by asking users where the file should go.  There's no real limit to what the executable can do (if you are a computer programmer and know how to design executable files to do what you want).

If you don't like how one piece of software (e.g., [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org)) makes a self-extracting Zip file, you may wish to try another type of self-extracting ZIP file (like one made with [Info-Zip.org](http://info-zip.org), or more specifically [WiZ](http://info-zip.org/WiZ.html)?), or use another method that can extract files (even though it is not an official ZIP file), like InstallShield.